# How to solve the proplem of missing blocks in gnu radio?

Tags: gnuradio

[Missing blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLZg3.jpg)

That are the missing blocks

Answer (score 0):

You have to find missing blocks by their names on https://packages.ubuntu.com .

The example for *dab_fic_decode* is [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=dab_fic_decode).

Then install needed package(s) by

```
sudo apt-get install gr-dab
```

and retry to run the simulation.